# How to detach and prependTo a div to a parent div that does not have a unique ID

Tags: jquery, wordpress, getelementsbyclassname, prepend

Working on moving a child element from within a DIV (h4) into it's parent DIV (two DIVs up the tree), using detach and prepend. The code I have is working but it takes every instance of this DIV on the page, and adds all the multiple DIV's on the page, to the top of every parent DIV.

```
jQuery( function($){
$('.mp_m_blurb_1 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('.mp_m_blurb_1 .et_pb_blurb_content');
});
```

I realize that on a page with multiple DIV elements of the same ID/class, this is what is going to happen. So how do I tell a child element to move to another parent DIV but only relative to its parent and without having to manually add a unique ID to each.

On some pages may have 10-15+ of these parent DIV's and I would prefer not to have to ad a unique ID to each one and then update my jQuery.

I would love to be able to use a single class. Is there a better way or approach?

Tried these resources but they did not help

[Move a div somewhere else in the dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789796/move-a-div-somewhere-else-in-the-dom)

[How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

[Get class name using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery)

[jQuery: appendTo parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679874/jquery-appendto-parent)

https://www.elated.com/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/

Below is the code that worked but as you can see, this is going to get long and tedious. ;-)

```
jQuery( function($){
$('#mp_blurb_0 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_0 .et_pb_blurb_content');
$('#mp_blurb_1 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_1 .et_pb_blurb_content');
$('#mp_blurb_2 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_2 .et_pb_blurb_content');
$('#mp_blurb_3 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_3 .et_pb_blurb_content');
$('#mp_blurb_4 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_4 .et_pb_blurb_content');
$('#mp_blurb_5 h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo('#mp_blurb_5 .et_pb_blurb_content');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of [jQuery's `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method and the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

Using `$('[id^="mp_blurb_"]')` will select all element with an ID starting with `mp_blurp_`.

```
$('[id^="mp_blurb_"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $this.find('.et_pb_blurb_content');
    $this.find('h4.et_pb_module_header').detach().prependTo( $content );
});
```

See my working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/z8of7qxp/